# how to reset input field after validation fails?

Tags: asp.net

I have a validator for a date input field. If the input is not in the MM/DD/YYYY format then it should throw an error and **clear the input**. I have tried Text="" property, but that doesn't work. And setFocusOnError is only working once.If I hit tab twice the field is losing foucs . Any ideas?

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="startDateValidator" Display="Dynamic"
                   ControlToValidate="dateStartDate" ValidationExpression="([0-9]|1[012])[/]([0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](19|20)\d\d" 
                   ErrorMessage="Start Date should be in MM/DD/YYYY format" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" 
                   />
```

**EDIT:** I want to know if this is possible using asp's validator controls.And why SetFocusOnError is not working as it's supposed to?

Comment: As a user, I'd really prefer if you didn't clear the textbox.

Comment: I would too.Hence my second question on why the validator loses focus.

Answer (score 1):

You should always validate on server side, additionally you can of course validate on client side (usability).

You can clear the textbox via javascript, but consider a user could have disabled javascript. That's also why you should always validate on server side.

```
<script language=JavaScript>
<!-- 
function clear_textbox()
{
    document.text_form.u_input.value = "";
} 
-->
</script>
```

You can run this script, you need to change u_input to your controls name.